# Typing inside a text input is extremely slow on iPad mini with iOS8 Mobile Safari and Safari 8

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari, ios8, ipad-mini

In mobile Safari (iOS 8.0 iPad Mini) it seems that, the more inputs (I've tried with different types) a web has, the slower the "typing" gets (I've even managed to freeze safari just typing). Just to make sure it was not the keyboard, I tested with Swiftkey, but the same problem arose. With Swiftkey, the input was fast, but the text was slowly inserted inside an input type text.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cmmg79u/1/embedded/result/) with some inputs and it really goes slow (as hell). At this fiddle, I added some select with lots of "option" tags because I found out that this makes the situation even worse. I also tried adding autocomplete attribute (set to false) but it doesn't seem to affect in any way.

This is more or less how would a "problematic" code look like:

```
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" />
<input class=""  type="email" autocorrect="off" />
<select><!-- lots of "option" tags --></select>
```

And now the weird thing: **this doesn't happen on an iPhone 5S** (didn't test it on any other iPad).

Does anybody know why this happens? Or if it happens on any other device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested on iPhone 5 iOS 7.1.1 everything is ok...

Comment: when you end your input, since safari is really sensitive about thing, and to keep good syntax, try adding an ending /> to your input!. So <input type="#" name="#" /> FOR EXAMPLE

Comment: Hi @ArmeniaH: In fact I was only able to reproduce this in iOS 8, and only iPad mini, on iPhone with iOS 8 it worked perfeclty.

Comment: About the input syntax, @md_5 you are right, I'll check out, but the first time I saw this was on a site with no such bad syntax. But as I said, I'll check it anyways.

Comment: As expected, the result is the same closing the input tags (which in fact is XHTML).

Comment: I really dont know why this is doing this for you. Ipad mini are up to date / safari with html5 and new updated features. Maybe its just your ipad!. Try downloading another browser from the appstore. Maybe google chrome. See if it does the same thing

Comment: And before we get started with anything, You will need to enclose <input> within <form> before using the inputs, or its just useless to have. Maybe not having or using <form> causing safari to throw errors and cause lag.

Comment: Do you have any javascript tied to these inputs, or any touch event listeners anywhere?

Comment: I have the same problem on the following form : http://bit.ly/mcchek which is fairly complex. Checked that on iPad 2/ iOS 8, iPhone 4S/iOS 8. I then downloaded chrome and it seems to fix the problem for me on my 4S w/ iOS 8.

Comment: @ryan I tried to disable javascript on safari on my 4S and I am still having the same issue

Comment: I just filled a bug to apple (#18626462 on radar). I encourage anyone having this issue to file another bug to make apple understand that this is a global issue.

Comment: The accepted solution also works for the same issue on Safari 8. I edited the title, hope it improves the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same issue as this one: [Why does Safari Mobile have trouble handling many input fields on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149532/why-does-safari-mobile-have-trouble-handling-many-input-fields-on-ios-8)

A workaround is to wrap each input element in a form element like this:

```
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="text" autocorrect="off" /></form>
<form><input class=""  type="email" autocorrect="off" /></form>
```

Comment: Incredible.. as ugly as it looks, it actually works! Thanks a lot. Anyways, Apple should fix this, because this is an awful work around.

Comment: Hi,
Even on Yosemite 10.10.x I've seen huge amounts of lag on certain websites including Stackoverflow.  I turned off my spellcheck which helped a little, but its more wide spread than just iOS.

Comment: This is still an issue in IOS15 / IPADOS15 ; yet, it seems just wrapping them in one form tag solved my issue.

Answer (score -3):

In order for the community to have the context: would you please share the entire source for one of the pages this issue is occurring on?

If you're trying to debug on a physical iPad I strongly recommend downloading [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) and opening the iPad emulator. From there you can view the console and a variety of other debugging tools. That should tell you an error for the speed and possibly propose a solution to fix it.

Comment: Hi, I just isolated the context where I'm getting the problem (and it's still happening with iOS 8.0.2 (only with iPad mini). The emulator doesn't behave like this, and as I said, I don't have any other iPad mini in hand to test. Anyways, I've done some research on the error log of the iPad, but nothing seems to be logged but the freeze of safari itself.
Kind Regards.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of using the emulator to debug. It's not that the issue will necessarily occur on the emulator (because you're using a desktop which has considerably more power typically) it's that you can use the debugger to see any errors that are being thrown which would give you insight into the issue. If the issue is with your application then you'll find it there. If nothing shows up that you may need to report it as a bug to Apple. I think the -1 vote isn't fair or respectful.

Comment: In fact I did try this on the emulator, and no error was shown, everything worked correctly with no strange log entries. I should probably report this bug to Apple then. (And just FYI I didn't down vote your answer).

Comment: Thanks for noting that you didn't vote my answer down. Apple has a good structure for reporting bugs so be sure to include your physical iPad model number and the full iOS version and that should be a good next step for you.