# Chrome slow down when numerous inputs on page

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am making a panel admin on my website and I need to render something like 200 - 500 rows and in each rows there are more or less 5 inputs and a couple of selects too, is there a way to stop Chrome from lagging with such things, went on the same page with Microsoft Edge and it's not lagging at all !
Chrome lag only when I add the inputs, with only the selects on the page it's not lagging.
I also have a javascript file called but when I take it off it lag the same way...
Found this topic : [Chrome is slow when there are a lot of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254646/chrome-is-slow-when-there-are-a-lot-of-inputs)
Tried the solution but didn't worked at all for me and the solution is for safari :(

Comment: I would suggest pagination

Comment: Then I would need to do ajax pagination because I have an ajax system to store tasks before sending them to PHP, is it possible to do something like that ( started javascript yesterday ^^ )
EDIT : Sorry for asking that googled it and found that it's possible of course... Will Chrome fix it someday because the other topic on stack overflow is 3 years old ^^

Comment: Hi, "Chrome is slow when there are a lot of inputs" - assuming your web page is populated from a Query>Result , consider altering the design of your web page to use pagination so that only a limited number of rows (do you mean table rows?....) are displayed at a time... If your do mean table rows, and you are changing the display style of rows to none and then to 'block', that is incorrect... tr.style.display='none' - hide a row.... tr.style.display=''; - revert back to the elements natural/default display rule (display='table-row').Include a reproduction link with your question if possible.

Comment: Yes it is table rows and effectively making inputs style="display: none;" make the page load and act normally without lags