# cursor exceeds the border when tap or select all content in input fields on iOS 8

Tags: html, ipad, input, ios8

IOS8 has the problem, IOS7 does not.
I have a input tag whose content's length is longer then its width.

```
<input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
```

when tap , the cursor exceeds the right border, see cursor.png.[image]

And when select all the select scroll also exceeds the border. see selectall.png[image]
Is anyone else happened the problem.Thanks!