# MacOS Safari many inputs, slow focus and typing is sluggish

Tags: html, jquery, web, safari

I have an html page which shows many rows of data which the user needs to be able to edit. So, a lot of input fields.

In every browser except for MacOS Safari there is no problem at all. In Safari however there are problems: clicking (focussing) on an input takes sometimes a few seconds. Typing....has some serious lag.

Having read a lot of topics i still do not have a working solution.

The one that somewhat works is wrapping EVERY individual input inside  tags. But, while typing then works without any lag, focussing still takes several seconds.
This solution, mentioned by Roman:

[Why does Safari Mobile have trouble handling many input fields on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149532/why-does-safari-mobile-have-trouble-handling-many-input-fields-on-ios-8)

I do not use any extensions or whatever, just plain MacOS Safari.

Does someone have any other solution that finally solves this strange behavior? I'm tearing my hair out here.